# Which storage method would be better to store images along with some text in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, file

I am creating an android app in which user can take a pic directly from camera or can choose it from gallery and can also put some text in Edittext box, like a form. Later the app will show all the feeded data in a Listview. Clicking on Listview item will open the detail page. Listview should display a thumbnail of the pic along with the text entered and detail page should display the whole pic with text.
I am very confused how to first save this data and which storage method would be efficient. Should I go for Sqlite or internal file storage? And then this whole thumbnail thing. If you can share any info, tutorial on how to do it would be appreciated :)

And forgive me, if this question is out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the storage engine you use, you should store the following:

1. Image file URI
2. String of entered text

These two elements can be stored using any of these options:

1. "Pure" SQLite
2. An ORM that wraps SQLite, providing more flexible functionality (ActiveAndroid, for example).
3. A non-SQLite DB, such as Realm (realm.io)
4. Store a list in shared preferences

Depends on how much data you have, and on how confident you feel with DBs in general.